# Expand folder structure in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I have a program do an action like "open file path" in windows 7, I get the explorer, it shows me the directory, but the tree on the left doesn't get expanded, which I would very much like.

Is there a setting I need to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **tools** menu >> **Folder options**

Check this setting:

[image]